# Fixed Div Stops Scrolling of inner div

Tags: html, css

I have run into a problem that a fixed div will swallow the scrolling for the parent div, however the scrolling for the page overall still works.

This can be seen in the following plunkr:
https://plnkr.co/edit/V1gbkrbhQduRFijlsrYz

The smaller sections can all be scrolled, but when they are clicked a fixed div is added that overlays that section. This stops the scrolling within that div, however there is also a small absolutely positioned paragraph at the bottom of each section.

Even when the fixed div is applied then scrolling on the absolute position paragraph still causes the inner div to scroll.

Does anyone know of a way to get the fixed div to pass the scroll to its parent container?

As a bit of background this is related to a modal that can have content go outside the modal and require scroll, however when a menu is opened in the modal then the scrolling breaks unless your mouse is directly over the menu. The plunkr was just to demonstrate the issue.

Code in plunkr:

Html:

```
<div class="container">
<p tabindex="1">
Lorem ipsum...
</p>
<div class="fixedOverlay"></div>
<p class="scrollableContent">I will let you scroll..</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}

p:focus + .fixedOverlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index:10;
}

p:focus {
  color: red;
}

.scrollableContent{
  position:absolute;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  z-index:11;
}
```

**Edit**
Just to clarify, I want to be able to scroll even when the mouse is over the main paragraph text, however as this will be an angular directive I only have control of the styling in the fixedOverlay and scrollableContent.

To give more insight into the reason for this the fixed overlay is used to capture when a user clicks off the menu so the menu can close

Comment: does this do what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/jalenconner/oejg11yw/

Comment: If that's what you're looking for I can expound a bit more in an answer but just wanted to make sure I understand what you are describing above before I do that.

Comment: hey, sorry if I wan't clear, I want it to always be able to scroll, even with mouse over the main paragraph text

Comment: hmmm I'm afraid I'm not getting what you're saying then.

Comment: If you want it to always scroll why have the fixed overlay?

Comment: I updated the question to give a bit more insight hopefully but the fixed overlay is to catch a click event so the menu will close when anything else is clicked